# JPersistentTree (JTree, boundtree) expand path to given node

Tags: java, database, swing, jtree, expand

I'm trying to use [**this package**](https://sites.google.com/site/uhilger/artikel_index/boundtree) to implement CRUD operations on categories of a store. I didn't know where to find people with experience of using this package, so I decided to ask here.

I wanted to add a quick search option, where the user can search for a category without browsing through the tree, and the selected path and node are expanded on the JTree.

So far, I've done the following:

```
ArrayList<FpsInventoryCategory> path;

    // recursive method to find the path to the root of a selected node
    private void findTreePath(FpsInventoryCategory currentNode) throws StorageException{
        Object parentId = currentNode.getParentId();
        FpsInventoryCategory parentNode = (FpsInventoryCategory) store.getItem(parentId);
        if (parentNode.isRoot()){
            path.add(0, parentNode);
        } else {
            path.add(0, parentNode);
            findTreePath(parentNode);
        }

    }
```

FpsInventoryCategory implements HierarchialItem. path is an ArrayList of FpsInventoryCategory. This works well and I'm able to get the desired path.

The problem I'm having is understanding the package in order to identify how to expand a node and/or TreePath. I had originally tried via a TreePath, but then realized that since the whole idea of a JPersistentTree is to dynamically load data, the JTree will not have data past the first row of children. Is this a correct assumption?

If so, then I'm assuming I have to load the children along the path which is what I tried as follows:

```
private void viewTreeNodeAndPath(Long id2) throws StorageException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
gui.getTreeInventoryCategory().getModel().getRoot();
            path = new ArrayList<FpsInventoryCategory>();
            store = gui.getStore();
            FpsInventoryCategory startNode = (FpsInventoryCategory) store.getItem(id);
            path.add(startNode);
            findTreePath(startNode);
            DynamicTreeNode currentTreeNode;
            Iterator it = path.iterator();
            int i = 0;
            FpsInventoryCategory temp;
            while(it.hasNext()){
                temp = (FpsInventoryCategory) it.next();
                System.out.println("temp cat:" + temp.getName());
                currentTreeNode = new DynamicTreeNode(store, temp);
                currentTreeNode.loadChildren();
                gui.getTreeInventoryCategory().expandRow(i);
                i++;
            }

//      selectedTreePath = new TreePath(dynamicNodePath);
//      System.out.println(selectedTreePath);
//      gui.getTreeInventoryCategory().setSelectionPath(selectedTreePath);
//      
//      gui.getTreeInventoryCategory().expandPath(selectedTreePath);

    }
```

^ Commented out selection by path as it was not producing results. This is equally not working.

Any idea of how I could get the tree to expand? Or even where I could get more info on this matter?

Please feel free to advise me or let me know where I can possibly find a solution to this.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi mKorbel, I can't seem to know/remember what you edited. I am working on a solution that requires traversing through the JPersistenttree from the root to the searched node, expanding all nodes in the path. Doesn't seem efficient, but I can't seem to expand the JPersistentTree by path. I'll post an answer later on today.

Answer (score 1):

Ok ... got it to work. Here's the code. Was doing some other things in between coding, so may leave a thing or two out.

I'll mention key fields (global variables) first, and then just point out the relevant methods. This is from a controller, MVC pattern.

```
private FpsInventoryCategoryTreeAdapter store;
    ArrayList<FpsInventoryCategory> path;
    TreePath selectedTreePath;
    private Long id;

// expand path and select node in JPersistentTree of category being searched
    private void viewTreeNodeAndPath() throws StorageException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        path = new ArrayList<FpsInventoryCategory>();
        store = gui.getStore(); // get store from gui (view contains HierarchicalDataStore implementation for JPersistentTree)
        FpsInventoryCategory startNode = (FpsInventoryCategory) store.getItem(id);  // id is the selected node as per quick search
        path.add(startNode);    // add selected node to path
        // find path from root to selected node
        findTreePath(startNode);
        int pathLength = path.size(); 
        TreeModel model = gui.getTreeInventoryCategory().getModel();
        DynamicTreeNode rootNode = (DynamicTreeNode) model.getRoot();
        // traverse through JPersistentTree from root to searched node, returning path to selectedTreePath
        searchThroughTree(model, rootNode, pathLength, 1);
        // expand selectedTreePath (from root to searched node)
        gui.getTreeInventoryCategory().setSelectionPath(selectedTreePath);
        gui.getTreeInventoryCategory().scrollPathToVisible(selectedTreePath);
    }

    // recursive method to find the path to the root of a selected node
    private void findTreePath(FpsInventoryCategory currentNode) throws StorageException{
        Object parentId = currentNode.getParentId();
        FpsInventoryCategory parentNode = (FpsInventoryCategory) store.getItem(parentId);
        if (parentNode.isRoot()){
            path.add(0, parentNode);
        } else {
            path.add(0, parentNode);
            findTreePath(parentNode);
        }

    }

    // recusrive method to get TreePath of searched node
    // pathSize: number of nodes from root to searched path
    // pathPosition: index of current node in path
    private void searchThroughTree(TreeModel model, DynamicTreeNode rootNode, int pathSize, int pathPosition){
        int childCount = model.getChildCount(rootNode);
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
            DynamicTreeNode childNode = (DynamicTreeNode) model.getChild(rootNode, i);
            if (model.isLeaf(childNode)){
                if (path.get(pathPosition).getId() == childNode.getUserObject().getId()){
                    selectedTreePath = getPath(childNode);
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (path.get(pathPosition).getId() == childNode.getUserObject().getId()){
                    if (pathPosition + 1 == pathSize){
                        selectedTreePath = getPath(childNode);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        pathPosition = pathPosition + 1;
                        searchThroughTree(model, childNode, pathSize, pathPosition);
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // find path from root to node
    public TreePath getPath(DynamicTreeNode node){
        List list = new ArrayList();
        // Add all nodes to list
        while (node != null){
            list.add(node);
            node = (DynamicTreeNode) node.getParent();
        }
        Collections.reverse(list);
        // Convert array of DynamicTreeNodes to TreePath
        return new TreePath(list.toArray());
    }
```

Working fine on my machine.